# How do I display and image from database to laravel blade?

Tags: laravel

I have followed the correctly marked answer in this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100119/how-do-i-capture-originalname-in-laravel-7-using-nowui-dashboard) to save images in my app. I am having trouble displaying the images to blade file. I am using `<img src="{{asset('/ProfileImages'.$p->profile_image)}}" alt="...">`  ProfileImages is the storage folder with structure **storage/app/ProfileImages**. How do I display the images as the above line doesnot display?

Comment: Have you run `php artisan storage:link` ?

Comment: @AmirAsyraf yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Laravel storage filesystem is so unique. When you doing any upload it will upload in the `storage/app/public` directory. To make it accessible in `public` directory, things need to do is create symlink by run command:*

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Or

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($p->profile_image) }} " alt=""/>
```

[StorageDocumentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#retrieving-files)

Answer (score 1):

use `Storage::url()`

```php
<img src="{{ Storage::url($p->profile_image) }}" alt="...">
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls

Answer (score 1):

By default when using `{{asset()}}` this will look inside your Public directory you should either consider storing photos inside your Public directory

Or take a look at the documentation about Laravel File System, here they explain how you can use storage directory and link it with your public directory
[Laravel File System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem)

Aslo you can use {{Storage::url()}} instead